# Issues with If/else-if statements - Text Based Adventure [C Programming]

Tags: c

[Text Based Adventure issue/question for lines (78-100)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1qc8.png)

Currently, in my first programming class, we are asked to do a project and a group project. The project my group chose was a text based adventure. I'm doing a majority of the work or doing research and ran into trouble and couldn't google my issue. My issue is, in the lines 78-100, I'm having to use an _ (underscore) to count as a space in my if/else statements. Is there a way I can have it to where anyone that plays this can just enter "Look around" as opposed to "Look_around"? I find that it could be extremely inconvenient having to always use an underscore to answer questions with more than one word. Any help and/or advice would be greatly appreciated.

My code is below:

```
// ConsoleApplication2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console 
application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h> // Allows the getch function //
#include <string.h> // Allows string/char functions //
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define getch() _getch() // Allows you to use getch()
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char user_input[25];
char name[50];
// user_input = (char)toupper(user_input); // This is example of what 
perhaps getting user_input to print capital letters //


printf("What is your name, weary traveler?\n\n"); // Introduction //
scanf("%s", name);
printf("You wake up to find yourself on the ground, in a dimmly lit room. \n");
printf("You stand up and look around, only to see a shadowy figure, it speaks, ");
printf("\nYou see %s, you're caught in a place that is both awake and dormant.\n", name);
printf("In this place, it's your fears that come to life, ones that'll haunt you,\n");
printf("in short, you're in your own nightmare. ");
printf("It's best you find a way to wake up soon or else you'll be trapped here forever. . .\n\n\n");


printf("------------------------------Press any key to continue-------------------------"); // End of introduction //
getch(); // Grabs any key hit and allows it to go to the next line of code //

system("cls"); // Clears screen so you can begin the game //
printf("\n\n\n----------------------Chapter 1: Nightmare on 2325 Chester Blvd-----------------\n\n\n"); // Begins Chapter 1 //
printf("You turn away from the shadowy figure to make sense where you are, ");
printf(" but when you turn back around to ask the figure where you are, you ");
printf("notice no one is there, you ask yourself \"Where am I?\"\n\n\n");
printf("You figure, to get the answers you seek, you must explore.\n");
printf("Where do you go? (Options: North/Up, East/Right, South/Down, West/Right)\n\n\n");
scanf("%s", user_input);


if ((strcmp(user_input, "North") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "north") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "Up") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "up") == 0)) { // This intends that you go North, expand onto this If statement to specify what happens if you go North //
    printf("\nYou are going up.\n");
}
if ((strcmp(user_input, "East") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "east") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "Right") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "right") == 0)) { // This intends that you go East, expand onto this If statement to specify what happens if you go East //
    printf("\nYou are going right.\n");
}
if ((strcmp(user_input, "South") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "south") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "Down") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "down") == 0)) { // This intends that you go South, expand onto this If statement to specify what happens if you go South //
    printf("\nYou are going down.\n");
}
if ((strcmp(user_input, "West") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "west") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "Left") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "left") == 0)) { // This intends that you go West, expand onto this If statement to specify what happens if you go West //
    printf("\nYou are going left.\n");
}
if ((strcmp(user_input, "Quit") == 0)) { // Without this if statement, the fourth If would only right "You're going left." Thus, this eliminates that so you can continue to have the if statement followed by the else statement.
    exit(0);
}


// Begin doing if statements for North and what inputs/scenarios would go into that "if" state

if ((strcmp(user_input, "North") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "north") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "Up") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "up") == 0)) { // This intends that you go North, expand onto this If statement to specify what happens if you go North //
    printf("\nYou walk down the hallway in front of you, you find several classroom doors shut, except one which seems to be cracked open, ");
    printf("however, you still haven't reached the end of the hall\n.");
    printf("\nWhat do you want to do? Where do you want to go? (Options: Straight/Forward or Classroom)\n\n");
    scanf("%s", user_input);
}

if ((strcmp(user_input, "Straight") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "straight") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "Forward") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "forward") == 0)) { // Can only use one word to do the printf line, meaning straight works but go straight doesn't //
    printf("You continue");
}

if ((strcmp(user_input, "Classroom") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "classroom") == 0)) {

    printf("You open up the half shut door of the classroom and begin to enter, only to see it's pitch black inside.");
    // You enter the classroom, it's dark. //
}

printf("\n\nWhat do you do?\n\n"); // Asks the user where they want to go, down the hallway or in the classroom //
scanf("%s", user_input);

if ((strcmp(user_input, "Look_around") == 0)) {// While loop that'll force users to have to look for a light source //

    printf("It's too dark to see, maybe there's a light source around here.");
    printf("\n\nWhat do you do?\n\n"); // loops back up //
    scanf("%s", user_input);
    printf("\n");
}

if ((strcmp(user_input, "Find_lightswitch") == 0)) {
    printf("The classroom light turns on. ");
    printf("You glance around the room and find that the desks are pushed against the back windows. \n");
    printf("You notice that the desks can be moved, but you don't know if you should.");
}

printf("\n\nWhat do you wish to do?\n\n");
scanf("%s", user_input);
printf("\n\n\n");

if ((strcmp(user_input, "Leave_classroom") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "Leave_the_classroom") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "Leave") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "Leave_room") == 0) || (strcmp(user_input, "Leave_the_room") == 0)) {
    printf("You attempt to leave the classroom, but find that the door is locked.");
}
else if ((strcmp(user_input, "Move_desks") == 0)) {
    printf("Moving the desks reveals, \"You are not dreaming\", is written in green on the window."); // \" and \" gives "and" //
    printf("You write on the window \"Yes I am\" and turn around and begin walking away, you hear a splash.\n\n");
    printf("\n\n\n");
}

printf("The Window - \"Yes you are.\"\n\n");
printf("\t\t\t\"No I'm not, wait are you just trying to confuse me?\" - %s \n\n", name);
printf("The Window - \"Yes, you seem like you could be fooled, so I fooled you\"\n\n");
printf("\t\t\t\"Well, I know I'm dreaming and that's that.\" - %s \n\n", name);
printf("The Window - \"Since I'm unable to fool you, so you say,");
printf(" you must answer these questions to be able to leave the room.\"\n\n");
return 0; //"You write on the window \"Yes I am\" and turn around and begin walking away, you hear a splash.\n\n");
```

}

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem ***as text***. We can't copy/paste pictures to source code.

Comment: You will get more help if you post the code here instead of a link

Comment: That is because `scanf("%s", user_input)` stops at the first whitespace. You should find a better way to input.

Comment: For reading input text with whitespace, either use the `%[` conversion specifier, or, even better, `fgets`.

Comment: I uploaded the code, sorry, first time posting. Used a lot of posts on this site before and it has been helpful for previous problems.

Comment: You totally do not want to be using `scanf` for this kind of input.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know exactly how many words the user will type in, you are better off using `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`.  `fgets()` will keep reading, up to a maximum number of characters, until a newline character is hit.  So you can read in the entire user input, and then figure out how to break it into words using blanks as seperators (`strtok()` would probably work ok in this situation).

```
# define MAX_INP 256

int main()
{
    char userInp[MAX_INP];

    if (fgets(userInp, MAX_INP, stdin) == NULL) {
        // handle error
    }

    printf("%s\n", userInp);

    // now break userInp into individual words
}
```

Your input buffer is `user_input`, `MAX_INP` should be equal to the size of your input buffer, in your example above, that would be 25.  In that case, at most 24 letters would be read and stored in `user_input` along with a terminating `\0`.  `stdin` means that you wish to read from standard in, instead of from a file.

I would look around for a manpage for `fgets()` for more details.  If you understand how `scanf()` works, it shouldn't be difficult to understand `fgets()`.

Comment: I haven't used fgets that much, as our instructor didn't even teach us it, he has us just use scanf. However, by your example, mine would be user_input, I'm assuming MAX_INP would be the 256, correct? After that, I believe stdin is just a function/feature that is pulled from somewhere else in the system?